# Matlab: script sum previous data

Tags: database, matlab, sum

I have a database, where each row is a tennis match, you can read ID_Tournament, ID_Round, DATE_Game, ID1 Player1, ID2 Player2, FirstServe Player1, DoubleFault Player1, FirstServe Player2, DoubleFault Player2. I have imported the file in mathlab and now I want to create new columns next to the last one (column I)

(PrintScreen made in excel)
https://image.ibb.co/f7ZFBv/demo.png

The new column should be the SUM of the previous match statics of that player. I'll give you an example referred to the image. I would like to know how many FS player1 had before in the row11 (ID1 488). So in J11 I'll read 47 (only one match before row11 occurred). Instead in row16 in J16 the player ID1 488 previously had 2 matches, so the correct data should be 47+52=99.
In each row I want to read the new data about previous matches.
How could it be script? How can I set a parameter that could indicate how many days one should look back?

Here you can find the workspace with the database.
https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/86955/demo.mat

In matlab answer an user gave me this script that actually works but not properly, however I think it's a good start:

```
load('demo.mat');
d = demoS1{:,[4,6]};
[a,ii] = sortrows(d,1);
[~,~,c] = unique(a(:,1));
d1 = accumarray(c,a(:,2),[],@(x){cumsum(x(:))});
d1 = cat(1,d1{:});
[~,i1] = sort(ii);
demoS1.last_column = d1(i1);
```

The script above use in the sum of previous match also the match that we are analyzing, and of course is incorrect. Also I can't set (or I don't know how) how many days (or previous match) the script have to take and put in the sum.

Need your help guys. Thanx in advance

Comment: To help geting an answer here are some suggestions: 
1) clean up the question and questiontext. It should be as short and consise as possible
2) document your code, i.e. describe with % what you are doing in that line. Generally speaking variables like a,b,c are not very useful code readability (which you want since you're sharing it)